# Combine two array, if date matched then sum using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two array a and b

```
a = [

      RowDataPacket { total_phone: 0, log_date: 2020-09-16T18:30:00.000Z },
      RowDataPacket { total_phone: 2, log_date: 2020-09-17T18:30:00.000Z },
      RowDataPacket { total_phone: 0, log_date: 2020-09-18T18:30:00.000Z },
      RowDataPacket { total_phone: 0, log_date: 2020-09-19T18:30:00.000Z },
      
    ]

b= [
  RowDataPacket {
    total_phone_calls: 1,
    date: 2020-09-16T18:30:00.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total_phone_calls: 11,
    date: 2020-09-17T18:30:00.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total_phone_calls: 5,
    date: 2020-07-24T18:30:00.000Z
  },
 
  }]
```

I have no idea how to do it. Any idea please..

> looking for c = [RowDataPacket { total: 1, log_date: 2020-09-16 }
> ,RowDataPacket { total: 13, log_date: 2020-09-17 }, RowDataPacket {
> total: 0, log_date: 2020-09-18 }, RowDataPacket { total: 0, log_date:
> 2020-09-19 },RowDataPacket { total: 5, log_date: 2020-09-24 }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

```js
const a = [
    { total_phone: 0, log_date: '2020-09-16T18:30:00.000Z' },
    { total_phone: 2, log_date: '2020-09-17T18:30:00.000Z' },
    { total_phone: 0, log_date: '2020-09-18T18:30:00.000Z' },
    { total_phone: 0, log_date: '2020-09-19T18:30:00.000Z' }
]

const b = [
    { total_phone_calls: 1, date: '2020-09-16T18:30:00.000Z' },
    { total_phone_calls: 11, date: '2020-09-17T18:30:00.000Z' },
    { total_phone_calls: 5, date: '2020-07-24T18:30:00.000Z' }
]

const obj = {}
a.forEach(item => {
  if (obj[item.log_date] === undefined) {
    obj[item.log_date] = item.total_phone
  } else {
    obj[item.log_date] += item.total_phone
  }
})
b.forEach(item => {
  if (obj[item.date] === undefined) {
    obj[item.date] = item.total_phone_calls
  } else {
    obj[item.date] += item.total_phone_calls
  }
})

const keys = Object.keys(obj)
const arr = []
keys.forEach(key => {
  arr.push({
    total: obj[key],
    log_date: key
  })
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Your logic is not adding total if both date matches in both  array

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I did upload the wrong answer :) it is updated now.

Comment: Thanks, your code saved me.. could you please help me on this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64905015/javascript-multiple-dimensional-array