# Javascript multiple dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a array

> [
> RowDataPacket {
> total: 1,
> deviceName: 'desktop',
> monthName: 'October'
> },
> RowDataPacket {
> total: 1045,
> deviceName: 'desktop',
> monthName: 'November'
> },
> RowDataPacket {
> total: 1783,
> deviceName: 'mobile',
> monthName: 'November'
> },
> RowDataPacket {
> total: 150,
> deviceName: 'tablet',
> monthName: 'November'
> }
> ]

I am trying to create an array like this

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 0,
    deviceName: 'mobile',
    monthName: 'October'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 0,
    deviceName: 'tablet',
    monthName: 'October'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 1,
    deviceName: 'desktop',
    monthName: 'October'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 1045,
    deviceName: 'desktop',
    monthName: 'November'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 1783,
    deviceName: 'mobile',
    monthName: 'November'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    total: 150,
    deviceName: 'tablet',
    monthName: 'November'
  }
]
```

I have tried following code to create the same but its not working as expected

```js
arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        finalarr.push[j] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Anyidea how to resolve this issue

Comment: can you put more details

Comment: that data structure does not make sense in javascript,
an array can only contain objects, and if you are trying to use a dictionary, then each key must be unique, the best you could do is create an array of objects like this: `[{ k1 : "v1"},{k1 : "v1"},{k1 : "v1"}]`

Comment: can you tell me how to do it please

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the data structure that you want, is not possible in javascript, however, this is the closest you can get to it.

```js
let internalObj = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}

let finalArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  finalArr.push(internalObj);
}

console.log(finalArr)
```

The results seems a little messy on stackoverflow, I suggest you try it out on your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you want to use `OOP` in Javascript. You need first define a class and then push instances into an array as follows.

```js
class RowDataPacket {
  constructor(data) {
    this.total = data.total
    this.deviceName = data.deviceName
    this.monthName = data.monthName
  }
}

const arr = [];
arr.push(new RowDataPacket({
  total: 0,
  deviceName: 'mobile',
  monthName: 'October'
}));
arr.push(new RowDataPacket({
  total: 0,
  deviceName: 'tablet',
  monthName: 'October'
}));
arr.push(new RowDataPacket({
  total: 1,
  deviceName: 'desktop',
  monthName: 'October'
}));
// push as many as you want.

console.log(arr);
```